# How to convert json to entity without root element?

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf

I have the following json string returned from a webservice. How would the JAXB annotated entity have to look like? My problem: the json does not have any "outer" root element.

```
{
"Header": "head",
"ProductIdentifier": "WLW",
"Version": "2"
}
```

//JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement
class JsonVO {
    private String header, productIdentifier, version;

    //constructor, getter, setter
}
```

unmarshal:

```
builder.get(JsonVO.class);
```

result:

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem
Schwerwiegend: No message body reader has been found for class com.craps.service.Reseed, ContentType: application/json
```

Comment: What library are you using for handling JSON?  MOXy?

Comment: I use CXF rs framework, and `jersey-media-json-processing` as json parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [JSON-P](https://jsonp.java.net/), you wont be able to directly bind the JSON response to your JAXB annotated beans.  You can do this with [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), which I use for this purpose.

First, add the MOXy dependencies to your project.  If you use Maven, you can add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When you consume the service, register the MOXyJsonProvider with your client:

```
client.register(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
```

The MOXyJsonProvider supports JSON without the root element by default, so you should not need any other configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is without using Moxy. Just modifying JSONProvider configuration.

Here is cxf configuration file

```
jaxrs:server id="KPService" address="/KPApp">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="kpBean" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>

            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
                <property name="dropRootElement" value="true" />
                <property name="dropCollectionWrapperElement" value="false" />
                <property name="ignoreNamespaces" value="true" />
                <property name="convention" value="mapped"/>
                <property name="unmarshallAsJaxbElement" value="true" />
                <!-- <property name="writeXsiType" value="false" /> -->
                <property name="readXsiType" value="false" />
            </bean>

            <ref bean="schemaGen"/>

        </jaxrs:providers>

        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </jaxrs:features>

    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="kpBean"
        class="com.rest.KPResource"></bean>

    <bean id="schemaGen" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
        <property name="linkJsonToXmlSchema" value="true" />
        <property name="schemaLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/json.schema</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="useJaxbContextForQnames" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreMessageWriters" value="false" />
        <property name="addResourceAndMethodIds" value="true" />
    </bean>
```